# Downsides of using a heavy gauge wire with low amperage?

Tags: cables, amperage

I understand that different gauges are available for different amperages. Is there any downside to using a cable that is able to support a high amperage for a low amperage?

Comment: It is heavy and not flexible. And expensive.

Comment: I don't physically have the cable but I'm assuming yes they would be heavier, stiffer and expensive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disadvantages are:

Cost.  Thicker cable costs more for the same length due to using more copper.

Weight.  Thicker cable weighs more for the same length.

More difficult to use.  Thicker cable is less flexible, which also reduces the options where it can be routed.  Very thick cable acts like a heat sink and is difficult to solder.

Less environmentally friendly.  Copper is a non-renewable resource.  The energy to mine it, refine it, form it into wire, and transport it also largely comes from non-renewable sources.  Even if you don't care about the cost, it's still irresponsible to use more of our resources than you really need.

Comment: dont forget that if you need to interface them with a pcb, they need more real estate there

Comment: @NilsPipenbrinck reusable, recyclable, is not renewable. There is a finite amount of copper on this planet, and we cannot create more (at this time)

Comment: 4.1.  Increased probability that somebody will recycle the copper cable prematurely (steal it and sell for scrap).

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any downside to using a cable that is able to support a high
>   amperage, for a low amperage?

Capacitance to ground and other conductors is a serious problem if your signals are high frequency. More difficult to twist and this means less ability to screen against high frequency RF interference.